# Running SPSS from Windows Command (CMD)

Tags: windows, cmd, spss

My SPSS **works fine with GUI**, but I want to start using syntax (`*.sps`) files and run SPSS from windows `CMD` without the GUI. The documentation
[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/spss/base/spss_command_line.htm) says it should be easy and specifies the following command:

```
stats C:\cars.sav C:\analysis.sps
```

However when I type this command SPSS launches the GUI and does nothing more. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the current directory when you type that command?  The docs say you need to run it from the installation directory.  Try typing the full path, as [shown here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=4c438955-1adc-45ef-b072-5e45b8e774b1).

Answer (score 0):

you want to utilize the production facility within SPSS.

https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/2014/12/03/automating-tasks-in-spss-using-production-jobs/

Comment: sorry, I thought the command line piece was in that article.

Once you have the production job set up, you can run the .spj file from the command line, or write a batch file to run it and set it up through windows scheduler: 

the command would look like this:

start C:\"Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\21\"stats -production silent H:\spss\money.spj

If you google "SPSS syntax command line production facility" a number of articles come up.